# Writing a text file to a mapped drive results in an error - "Could not find a part of the path"

Tags: c#, iis, .net-core, mapped-drive

1. I have mapped network path (\fileserver\myfolder\dev) to "N:" drive using user "abc"
2. Writing a file to drive using path "N:"
3. My IIS is running under application pass through.

It's working in local but when I deploy it to DEV server it's not working there. It's throwing the error

> "Could not find a part of the path"

Not sure what needs to be done?

Comment: Is that location mapped to drive "N" on the server? Does the IIS App Pool have access to that directory?

Comment: Location is mapped to "N" drive on server. Not sure how to give access through IIS

Comment: You right click on the folder (directory) while logged on to the server, your app pool which is running your application has a name when you create it, you then go under security of the properties option when right clicking the directory, add user, then instead of using domain\something, you use     (make sure there is a space in IIS AppPool\AppPoolName)    
 IIS AppPool\AppPoolName, search on whole computer (Server name), should then locate that as a valid user, set up the security options as you see fit.

Comment: @RyanWilson - Thanks! I For now, I entered user credentials in Identity of AppPool which user has access to shared path and used UNC path in my code. This is working for me now. Not sure if this is best method. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You're welcome. If the domain account you are using to run the app pool is secure (strong password) I don't see anything wrong with your approach, I have a couple applications that run under a dedicated domain account so that the application can do things like send documents to a network printer and another one which utilized HttpClient to call out to an API which is using Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 1):

IIS runs under a different account and might not see the mapped drive.
Try the UNC path //fileserver/myfolder/dev

if that does not work, if you have a username/password that can access the mapped path u can try impersonation

```
public static class ImpersonationContext
        {

        private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

        static WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName,
            String lpszDomain,
            String lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            ref IntPtr phToken);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
            int impersonationLevel,
            ref IntPtr hNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);


        public static bool ImpersonateUser(String userName, String domain, String password)
            {
            WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (RevertToSelf())
                {
                if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
                    {
                    if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                        {
                        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                        impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                        if (impersonationContext != null)
                            {
                            CloseHandle(token);
                            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                            return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(token);
            if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
            return false;
            }


        // MADE CHANGE HERE TO IMPERSONATION TO CHECK FOR NULL BEFORE PERFORMING ANY METHOD...WAS CAUSING PROBLEMS
        public static void UndoImpersonation()
            {
            if (impersonationContext != null)
                {

                impersonationContext.Undo();
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: UNC path is not working. Will this Impersonate work with .NET CORE?

Comment: that is code i used in .net 4.5, if your core app is on a windows server then yes,